# MVC Area using multiple solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

I am using below link to devide Area into multiple application.

http://geekswithblogs.net/cokobware/archive/2013/01/15/asp.net-mvc-4-pluggable-application-modules.aspx

Where, we create Area folder in one project and we provide the actual implementation in another project, which itself is created in the same path where Area folder lies in first application.

Our requirement is to create Areas in altogether different solution instead of a different project

I tried the same but it does not seems to be working.

Is it possible to create Areas in separate solution and call the views of that area from main MVC web application which has the Area folder?

Has anyone came across such situation?